# There is a warning when importing resources under the public folder using Vite

Tags: javascript, frontend, vite

I used ***import.meta.globEager()*** to import the picture resources under the public folder. The console gives me these tips, but if I remove'/public'and I can't get these pictures, how can I remove these tips?

> `const Assets = import.meta.globEager('/public/static/user_preference/stage_color_png/*.png');`

and then give me some tips:  **files in the public directory are served at the root path.Instead of /public/static/user_preference/stage_color_png/1.png?import, use /static/user_preference/stage_color_png/3.png**

Comment: Use the tip and change it to "/static/user_preference/stage_color_png/*.png'"